# Proyecto con Crystal Reports muestra Report Viewer sin datos y en gris

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports, reportviewer

Tenemos un proyecto con el que venimos trabajando sin problemas, descargamos la versión más reciente del proyecto desde el repositorio de Visual Studio Online y al unirlo a los últimos cambios (merge) dejó de mostrarnos todos los reportes y solo nos pone el Report VIewer en gris y sin datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estamos trabajando con Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3 (14.0.25431.01) y con CR 13.0.2000.

Cabe mencionar que el problema se presenta en dos computadoras que tenemos el proyecto; y otros proyectos abren los reportes sin problemas en ambas computadoras.

Espero nos puedan ayudar con sus respuestas para solucionarlo.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Estas seguro que la distribucion Community del VS no soporte Crystal? Desde el Explorador de Soluciones puedes seleccionar un .rpt y ver su diseño?

Comment: Estás en lo correcto, oficialmente la página de Crystal Reports dice que no soporta versiones Express no menciona nada acerca de Community, sin embargo si puedo ver los diseños y como les comento otros proyectos si funcionan.   https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/06/sap-crystal-reports-developer-version-for-microsoft-visual-studio-updates-runtime-downloads/